# How to find event listeners on an element using firefox like get function "getEventListeners" in chrome?

Tags: dom-events, javascript-objects, firefox-developer-tools

I'm using firefox to collect all event on an element.but there is no api to gather the event like function "getEventListeners" in chrome.

I notice that there shows the event in the firefox devtools Inspector:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUpiu.png)

so I guess there is a way to get the event too,but I did't find it out

Answer (score 0):

This functionality does not exist in Firefox, and is only available in Chromium browsers through its [`DOMDebugger` API](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOMDebugger/#method-getEventListeners).
The reason for not adding it as a helper likely has to do with

- API-compatibility/security concerns (see [WHATWG proposal](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/412))
- lack of compatibility with Firefox/Gecko internals (the spec does not describe an API for accessing listeners, so support may require additional instrumentation)
- lack of interest in supporting such a feature (see [enhancement request from 2015](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1164285))

or maybe some combination of these.
I'd wager the lack of interest supersedes most of these reasons, as both Chromium and Firefox have since integrated this feature into their Dev Tool GUI's.

Nevertheless, a *somewhat* similar behavior can be achieved in Firefox by using `inspect(element)` to jump to the specified DOM element (see [Web Console Helpers](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/helpers/index.html)). This is possibly useful if you have a reference to an element and would like to quickly find it in the tree.

[image: before calling inspect]

[image: after calling inspect on , the element is selected]

Then you can click the `event` button to show the registered listeners as you would.

A funky side effect of this is if an element exists on the page with `id="inspect"` then it will override the built-in `inspect(element)` helper function due to [a quirk in the HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-access-on-the-window-object:the-id-attribute).
[image: dev tools inspect points to element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/devtools/inspectedWindow/eval#inspect rather than helper function]